# Cutting out using DD command

Tags: partitioning, dd

I need to cut out a partition, using DD command. How do I achieve this? In my case I need to copy from block 205267 to (including this block) 29311545. The blocksize is 512 Bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with:

```
# make sure you set the right paths for sdX
dd if=/dev/sdX of=~/outputfile bs=512 skip=205266 count=29106280
```

Explanation of options:

```
 if=     describes the inputfile path
 of=     describes the output file path
 bs=     states the blocksize in bytes
 skip=   skips bs size blocks at the beginning of input file
 count=  read N blocks (so in your case N = (End+1)-Begin)
```